# A problem with "news"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know news doesn't have a plural, but what is correct in the following example:

*We must recognize real news from fake **one**.*

or

*We must recognize real news from fake **ones**.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: Related https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/68501/9161

Comment: @ColleenV: Nicely found. It's nowhere near a "duplicate", imho, but definitely extremely relevant.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Definitely not a duplicate, but I wanted to link it just in case someone with the other question found this discussion first. I wish there was a way to see the “related links” section of the sidebar in the mobile view.

Comment: @ColleenV: Oh! I've only just noticed that **Linked** *4 News for plural* on the sidebar (I'm on a PC desktop). I always assumed the **Related** list was just based on an automated search for earlier posts having many words / text sequences in common with the current one. I didn't even realise there was such a thing as **Linked** (which I assume arises purely because ***you*** put that link in your comment - or is it a "mod thing" that you can explicitly set the sidebar notification?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Any ELL question linked in a comment/answer/question by anyone should appear there. The Contributor’s Guide on [meta] is a good example of a fully populated “Linked” list.

Comment: @ColleenV: This is a lot for me to take in all in one day! I've also just worked out for myself that the "Upvote Count for the Question" value shows in green *if there's an accepted answer*. I should make a point of remembering that, because assuming I've already engaged with the *current* question, it should on average be easier / quicker / more trustworthy for me to see if there's a single "obviously best" answer on a linked question. So if I haven't already voted there, I should do so to help raise its prominence (which I think becomes more important if there's no "Accepted Answer").

Answer (score 20):

Neither; either repeat “news” or omit it entirely:

“We must distinguish real news from fake news.”

“We must distinguish real news from fake.”

Comment: Interestingly, although I have at least "misgivings" about the usage, I found a few dozen written instances of [***long trousers, not short ones***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22long+trousers+not+short+ones%22) in Google Books. But you're quite right that we *definitely* can't / don't / won't use that construction with ***news***.

Comment: His question is still somewhat valid, why isn't it valid to say "We must distinguish real news from fakes?"

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's simply because news doesn't have a plural. "Ones" works in any case where you can refer to the noun as "those", such as "those trousers". No reason to have misgivings about this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's because "trousers" is plural.  One "trouser" is just a tube of material.  During the middle-ages, people in Europe would wear a tube of material on each leg (a.k.a. "hose" - or, in Scotland, "trews" which then became "trouser") with a codpiece in the centre.  Someone then re-invented the idea of stitching both tubes together with some extra material ("a pair of trousers") - which Asians had already been doing since the 10th Century BC for riding horses...

Answer (score 13):

You're right.   The word "news" doesn't have a plural form.   That fact is a good reason to avoid using the pronoun "one".

There is a useful description for nouns that don't have plural forms.   We call them *strictly uncountable*.   As either an adjective or a pronoun, the word "one" involves counting.

Your examples are trying to count something that is strictly uncountable.

Comment: I found [*A fourth class of bipartite nouns (e.g. **scissors, trousers**) is generally recognised for English.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22fourth+class+of+bipartite+nouns%22) Might that be as opposed to "not so strictly uncountable" nouns, that we can reference with *I want the sharp scissors, not the blunt ones*, or *He's wearing short trousers, not long ones* - whereas we *can't* do anything like that with ***news***.

Comment: I don't see much similarity between *pluralia tantum* and strictly uncountable nouns like "news" and "software".  The idea of something being uncountably plural doesn't make sense to me.  The lack of a singular form and the lack of a plural form have different consequences.

Comment: But surely ***trousers*** and ***scissors*** *are* "uncountably plural", in that we have to use ***ones*** rather than ***one*** in my examples above. Whatever - [*Apparently the news **are** good*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Apparently+the+news+are+good%22) (or ***were***, back in Carlyle's day), but today the news can only take a singular verb form.

Comment: Yes, we use the plural form "ones" to agree with the plural form "trousers".  That's evidence of counting, rather than evidence of a lack of counting.  We're distinguishing between *one* and anything *other than one* -- a very limited counting, but that's all that English grammar provides.

Comment: Perhaps the very fact that it's invariably ***the** news* implies that at any given time we normally only think of ***all current news*** as being the only news there is. Except when we want today's rather than yesterday's news, or real news rather than fake. I just look forward to the day when fake news will be synonymous with yesterday's news.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Trousers and scissors aren't uncountable. They come in pairs.

Comment: @Shufflepants: Ditto ***pants***, whichever side of the pond they come from, with whichever meaning (*and* regardless of whether they're shuffled, or in some preset sequence! :)

Answer (score 9):

When we use the word "news" as in your examples, it refers to news in general, not specific articles. Therefore, it's an uncountable noun, and you can't use a singular pronoun to refer to it.

If you want to refer to a specific piece of news, we call it an "article" or "item". So you could write:

> We must recognize real news articles from fake ones.